# Storing multiple values for a single variable (PDO)

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a MySQL table that stores user emails:

```
user_id    |    user_phonenumber
----------------------------
id1        |    555-123456789
```

I want to allow the user to store multiple phonenumbers and I don't want to limit the number of numbers a user can be associated with.

What's the best way of structuring my data, and how would a query work in PDO?

For example, should I store them all in the same field with comma separators and then parse the output when the query is returned, or should I use another table and have each row as a separate number with common user_ids? How would a lookup work then (please provide example code if possible)?

Thanks

Comment: Use a table with a row for each email address for each user. Having a comma separated list is a nightmare (eg, if you want to find the user with the email address of fred@somecompany.com you would need to use find_in_set or LIKE with leading and trailing % signs - both of which would not use indexes and would be slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally RDBMS systems are designed to access fields/rows. Everything will be much harder when you start to break the data-field link/consistency/logic.
I mean when you start to store more data in a single field.

But you know your system's future. It can happen that you won't ever have to access for example the first phone number, and if you can handle it everywhere as a blob then it can be fine to store more values in a single field.

Anyway If this is not a homework or similar short living task then you should choose the 1 phone number/1 record approach.

I mean something like this can be future proof:

```
create table user_phonenumbers(
  id          auto_increment primary key.
  user_id     integer references user(id),
  phonenumber varchar(32)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, so assume I have a separate table with 2 phonenumbers for 1 id, what would a query look like?

Comment: I added an example table structure. You can select normally from this new table also. I don't understand 100% your question...

Comment: Sorry, I mean, say I wanted to return all the phonumbers from user_phonenumbers, how would the PDO statement look?

Comment: If you want to get a comma separated list of phone numbers for each user then you could use SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(phonenumber) FROM user_phonenumbers GROUP BY user_id

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use another table to store user phone numbers.
use inner join to lookup, it would be good.